# JavaFX, problem with Platform.runLater(), delayed rendering of Canvas graphic

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, event-handling

I am trying to make a simple event driven TicTacToe game using JavaFX. Currently I am struggling with termination once certain conditions are met. To put it into more details, the player can click on the `GridPane` elements, which are `Canvas` Objects, and then they are filled with "X" or "O" shapes respectively (I am using `strokeLine` and `strokeOval` methods of `GraphicsContext`). Code below:

```
private static void placeX(Canvas square){
    GraphicsContext gc = square.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.setLineWidth(10.0f);
    gc.setStroke(Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);
    gc.strokeLine(square.getWidth()*0.2, square.getHeight()*0.2, square.getWidth()*0.8, square.getHeight()*0.8);
    gc.strokeLine(square.getWidth()*0.8, square.getHeight()*0.2, square.getWidth()*0.2, square.getHeight()*0.8);
}
```

Once 3 of the same shapes appear in line or diagonally the program should terminate. I am doing this using `Platform.exit()`. Code below:

```
class HandleGame implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent e){


        Canvas can = (Canvas)e.getTarget();
        //function to check if the canvas is clear 
             placeX(can);  

         if(game.isEnded()){  //checks if the same shape appears three times

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException exc){
                        System.out.println("Got something: " + exc.getMessage());
                    }
                    Platform.exit();
                }
            });
        }
    } 
}
```

This event handler is attached to every `Canvas` object in `GridPane` and triggers on mouse release. The problem I am having is that once the last `Canvas` is clicked, before the shape appears on the `Canvas` the specified `Runnable` is executed and the rendering is unnaturally delayed (the "X" shape appears only for a second before closing). Strangely enough 1 out of 10 runs it executes as expected. How can I make the rendering trigger before the `Thread.sleep()` and following `Platform.exit()`? Why on rare occasions the rendering is actually performed before `Thread.sleep()`? I did a little research but could not find anything decisive, I am newbie when it comes to JavaFx. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that the `Thread.sleep` is sleeping the _rendering thread_. If you want to create a delayed action on the FX thread use a `Timeline`, `PauseTransition`, or `AnimationTimer`. As to why sometimes it renders before exiting? That's subject to the scheduling of `Platform.runLater` which, "_[runs] the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some **unspecified time** in the future_".

Comment: What Slaw said.  You cannot sleep in the JavaFX application thread.  Other options are simply creating a new thread and sleeping in its Runnable, or using a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I used `PauseTransition`  and also tried running a separate `Thread`. Both solutions work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Slaw and @VGR comments I managed to solve the problem using two different methods, one utilizing `PauseTransition` and second `Thread`. Code below:

Using `PauseTransition`:

```
if(game.isEnded()){
    PauseTransition termination = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1d));
    termination.setOnFinished(event -> Platform.exit());
    termination.play();
}
```

Using `Thread`:

```
if(game.isEnded()){

    new Thread(() -> {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException exc){
            ; //exception handling code here
        }
        Platform.exit();       
    }).start();*/
```